# two foreach in one table codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

controller

```
    $data['detail'] = $this->M_internal_mutation->show_detail_opb($imno,$imdate,$fromwarehouse);

    $data['stock'] = $this->M_internal_mutation->tampil_stock($pcode,$imdate,$fromwarehouse);

    $this->load->view('internal_mutation_showOpb_detail',$data);
```

View

```
<?php $no=1; foreach ($detail as $key) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><?php echo $key->inventorycode ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $key->inventoryname ?></td>
<?php } ?>
<?php foreach($stock as $a){ ?>
    <td><?php echo $a->stock_awal ?></td>
 </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

how to put 2 foreach in the one table? 
because the way I use this still does not work

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? please add more details to your question.

Comment: how to put 2 foreach in the one table? because the way I use this still does not work

Comment: By doesn't work, what do you mean exactly? any errors? what do you get and what are you expecting?

Comment: If I guess what you're trying to achieve, you can't loop twice in the same table. Why not JOIN the tables from database so you get all results in same query?

Answer (score 1):

You can put a key on the loop and display values, example:

```
   <?php foreach($detail as $index => $key){ ?> 
    <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td><?php echo $key->inventorycode ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $key->inventoryname ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $stock[$index]->stock_awal ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```